# weird issue with PM2 start

Tags: python, pm2, ubuntu-20.04

I have a python3 application that I want to run continually on an Ubuntu server. I'm managing it using pm2, but running into a very strange error.

I am starting the pm2 process using:

```
pm2 start --name python_app --watch --interpreter /usr/bin/python3.8 python_app.py
```

When I *first* run this, it doesn't start properly: pm2 continually stops and restarts the process multiple times per second, and will keep doing this unless stopped. The output of the pm2 error logs makes very little sense: it's a lot of very long tracebacks through python libraries (almost always Flask), but without any actual errors attached to them, other than KeyboardInterrupts, which I am not making.

After manually stopping and starting the app (using the commands below), everything runs as expected (and then continues to work fine for subsequent restarts).

```
pm2 stop python_app
pm2 start python_app
```

I have repeated this process (deleting and remaking the pm2 process to see the error, and then stopping and restarting to make it work) multiple times, with the same results every time. I wonder whether this is the result of something else that's not right? Or, whether there's an equivalent command in pm2 to 'setup' a new process without launching it, then starting it separately.

I tried increasing the startup memory that pm2 could use, but it just uses 100% of whatever I give it, and still experiences the same restarting issue (just much faster, haha).

Answer (score 1):

ah, I think I know what the issue was: I noticed that watching appeared as 'disabled' when I listed processes, even though I had run with the --watch command.

When I removed `--watch` from the `start` command, it worked fine: perhaps it's not meant to be used with Python?

Would love to hear from anyone who knows more, but problem solved.